# Lua: iterate table (with alphanumeric values) on two specific columns

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I have this code that iterates the Lua table "childrenTable" to retrieve its values, but I want them **sorted** by the column **"symbolicname"** *and then*, by the column **"name"**

- The table contents in this example are inserted, but in my real scenario they are  automatically populated, so I cannot control how they get in the table. I'll insert contents here just for having the table populated:

```
    local JSON = require 'dkjson'

    local childrenTable = {}
    
    childrenTable[1] = {symbolicname = "02 CONNECTOR", path = "system/core/b connector", name = "b connector"}
    childrenTable[2] = {symbolicname = "02 CONNECTOR", path = "system/core/a connector", name = "a connector"}
    childrenTable[3] = {symbolicname = "01 CORE", path = "/system/core/b", name = "b"}

    childrenTable[4] = {symbolicname = "01 CORE", path = "/system/core/a", name = "a"}    
        
    for index,value in ipairs(childrenTable) do print(JSON.encode(value)) end
```

**This is returning this result right now:**

```
{"name":"b connector","symbolicname":"02
CONNECTOR","path":"system/core/b connector"}

{"name":"a connector","symbolicname":"02
CONNECTOR","path":"system/core/a connector"}

{"name":"b","symbolicname":"01 CORE","path":"/system/core/b"}

{"name":"a","symbolicname":"01 CORE","path":"/system/core/a"}
```

***But I want it to return the list in order:***

```
{"name":"a","symbolicname":"01 CORE","path":"/system/core/a"}

{"name":"b","symbolicname":"01 CORE","path":"/system/core/b"}

{"name":"a connector","symbolicname":"02
CONNECTOR","path":"system/core/a connector"}

{"name":"b connector","symbolicname":"02
CONNECTOR","path":"system/core/b connector"}
```

Thanks in advance,

Roger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `table.sort` function, it will iterate through the table and pass you an item at the left and right wing of the current index. (`table.sort` is based in quicksort algorithm)

This will work for you:

```lua
local childrenTable = {}
childrenTable[1] = {symbolicname = "02 CONNECTOR", path = "system/core/b connector", name = "b connector"}
childrenTable[2] = {symbolicname = "02 CONNECTOR", path = "system/core/a connector", name = "a connector"}
childrenTable[3] = {symbolicname = "01 CORE", path = "/system/core/b", name = "b"}
childrenTable[4] = {symbolicname = "01 CORE", path = "/system/core/a", name = "a"} 

table.sort(childrenTable, function(a, b)
    if a.symbolicname < b.symbolicname then
        return true
    else
        if a.name < b.name then
            return true
        else return false end
    end
    return false
end)

for k,v in pairs(childrenTable) do print(k, v.name, v.symbolicname) end
```

Also, for large amounts of data, consider using a dataframe.

Comment: Your sorting function contains an error (what if `a.symbolicname > b.symbolicname` but `a.name < b.name`? It should return `false` but will return `true`) and could be simplified:
`return a.symbolicname < b.symbolicname or a.symbolicname == b.symbolicname and a.name < b.name`

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks to both @Alexander Mashin (your fix is ok) and Coal, and also thanks to luther for the corrections !